# alt/title attributes in img-tag in typo3

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I use the following Typoscript to get a menu of pages with images from respective page resource.
How can i get the page-title (or page-description etc.) to the images alt and/or title-tags?

```
tt_content.menu.20.4 >
tt_content.menu.20.4 = COA
tt_content.menu.20.4 {
    wrap = <div>|</div>
    10 = HMENU
    10 {
        special = directory
        special.value.field = pages
        1 = TMENU
        1 {
            noBlur = 1
            NO = 1
            NO {
                stdWrap >
                stdWrap {
                    cObject = COA
                    cObject {
                        10 = FILES
                        10 {
                            references {
                                table = pages
                                uid.data = field = uid
                                fieldName = media
                                data = levelmedia:-1, slide
                                treatIdAsReference = 1
                                listNum = 0
                            }
                            renderObj = IMG_RESOURCE
                            renderObj {
                                file.import.data = file:current:publicUrl
                                file.maxW = 100
                                file.maxH = 60
                                required = 1
                            }
                        stdWrap.wrap = <img src="|" title="???pagetitle???" alt="???pagetitle???">
                        }
                    }
                }
                wrapItemAndSub = <div>|</div>
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it with dataWrap?

i think it could be something like this

```
stdWrap.dataWrap = <img src="|" title="{field:title}" alt="{field:title}">
```

or maybe...

```
stdWrap.dataWrap = <img src="|" title="{page:title}" alt="{page:title}">
```

Answer (score 0):

this works for me now

```
cObject = COA
cObject {
 10 = FILES
 10 {
  references {
    table = pages
    uid.data = field = uid
    fieldName = media
    data = levelmedia:-1, slide
    treatIdAsReference = 1
    listNum = 0
  }
  renderObj = COA
  renderObj {
   10 = IMG_RESOURCE
   10.stdWrap.wrap = <img src="|
   10.file.import.data = file:current:publicUrl

   20 = TEXT
   20.stdWrap.wrap = " title="|
   20.data = file:current:title

   30 = TEXT
   30.stdWrap.wrap = " alt="|" />
   30.data = file:current:title
  }
  stdWrap.wrap = |
  stdWrap.required = 1
 }
}
```